# boost::process doesn't work in Cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

Trying to complie the following code in Cygwin environment:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main() { }
```

And get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/process/detail/child_decl.hpp:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/process/child.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/process/async_system.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/process.hpp:24,
                 from bp.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/process/detail/posix/is_running.hpp:18:1: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
 static_assert(!WIFEXITED(still_active), "Internal Error");
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cygwin/stdlib.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:26,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6349,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/system_error:41,
                 from /usr/include/boost/process/detail/config.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/process/detail/basic_cmd.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/process/args.hpp:33,
                 from /usr/include/boost/process.hpp:22,
                 from bp.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/process/detail/posix/is_running.hpp:18:16: error: call to non-constexpr function 'int __wait_status_to_int(int)'
 static_assert(!WIFEXITED(still_active), "Internal Error");
                ^
```

Could you suggest how to fix it?

I'm using Boost 1.66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WIFEXITED macro expands to a function call to __wait_status_to_int.
This one can't be called at compile time.

This is a bug in <del>boost process</del> in Cygwin.

According to

https://github.com/openunix/cygwin/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/include/sys/wait.h

__wait_status_to_int is a macro and for C++ they remove the macro and instead they provide two overloaded functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As a temporary workaround I comented this redefinition, and it works now! Also I've send a bug report to a cygwin mailing list.